# Adding strings to a file without storing them in memory first

Tags: linux

Could someone explain to me why this takes up all the memory on my computer?

This is what I did:

```
./program.sh >> file.txt
```

Here is what program.sh looks like:

```
for i in {0..999999999}
do
    echo SET key_$i 'This is the value of the key'
done
```

Comment: You must be doing something odd because the command you posted above should have little memory impact.

Comment: It sounds like your `program.sh` is storing all the strings in memory internally. If so, you need to fix `program.sh`. There is nothing else you can do.

Comment: It might be that your program buffers its output.

Comment: Ok I have posted what the script looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{0..999999999}` is expanded before it is passed to the `for` cycle.

Use `while` cycle instead:

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 999999999 ]; do
    echo SET key_$i 'This is the value of the key'
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```